# FFMPEG using a screen capture for an overlay results in serious visual flaws

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to overlay a screen capture of a specific window on top of a background image, and output the result - it works but results in unacceptable visual flaws.

The command I'm using is:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 30 -i background.jpg -f gdigrab -r 30 -i title=Calculator \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10[video]" -map "[video]" -c:v libx264 \
-f flv output.flv
```

which places a screencap of the calculator window on the background at position 10,10.

This is what the output looks like:

[image: overlay screenshot]

All the buttons on the calculator are super muddied and appear bold, almost as if it was overlaid several times at slightly different positions. Is there something wrong with the command or any way to fix it and preserve visual integrity of the original? Changing the output format doesn't have any effect, nor does setting `-crf 0` or adjusting any other encoding settings.

This doesn't happen when I screen capture just the calculator by itself without overlaying it on anything. For reference here is what the output looks like when I only record the calculator with no overlaying:

[image: calc-only screenshot]

Comment: Try specifying a bitrate, ref: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: Show the full log.